# PHP code is only partially updating on webpage

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I submitted a question yesterday about this code, but I ran into another problem. I also suspect that there are errors in escaping and whatnot, so any input is greatly appreciated.

There are two items on the page that can be donated. The number of required items changes based on what has been donated, which is stored in the database. Only one of the items numbers are changing though. Here's the code:

```
$amount_left = $db->query("SELECT required_items.name AS Name, required_items.required_amount - donations.donation_amount AS Amount_Left 
                            FROM required_items AS r JOIN donations AS d ON d.item_id=r.id");

// Print out the table tag and header
echo("<form name=\"donationForm\" action=\"" . $pageName ."\" method=\"POST\">\n<fieldset>");
echo("<table>\n");
echo("<tr>\n<th>Item Name</th><th>Amount</th>\n</tr>\n");

try{    
    // Round negative amounts to zero
    if($amount_left['Amount_Left'] < 0){
        $amount_left['Amount_Left'] = 0;
        }

        // Create a new table row
        echo("<tr>");
        // Create a new table cell for the name and required_amount fields
        echo("<td>" . $amount_left['Name'] . "</td>");
        echo("<td>" . $amount_left['Amount_Left'] . "</td>");
        echo("<td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"radioButtons\" value=\"". $row['id'] ."\"></input></td>");
        echo("</tr>\n");

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    // Catch all errors and print them out
    echo("Error: ");
    echo($e->getMessage());
}

// Close the table and create our submit button
echo("</table>\n<br>\n");
echo("<div>\n<label>Amount</label>\n<input type=\"number\" name=\"amount\">\n</div>\n");
echo("<div>\n<label>Email</label>\n<input type=\"email\" name=\"email\">\n</div>\n");
echo("<div>\n<label>Name</label>\n<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\">\n</div>\n");
echo("<div>\n<input type=\"submit\" name=\"donate\" value=\"Donate\" />\n</div>\n");
echo("</fieldset>\n</form>\n")
```

The database contains two required items, the first asks for a quantity of 20, the second - a quantity of 10. The second one does not update it's number based on donations in the database.

Also is there any advantage to echoing all the html? or can I just put it on the web page?

EDIT: To clarify on my end, the database includes two tables, one for required_items and one for donations.

required_items has: id, name, required_amount

donations has: id, name, email, donation_amount, item_id

Comment: I'd prefer NOT to `echo` the HTML and use the `<?php` tags to separate the code.

Comment: @Havelock Is there any reason to do it or is it just preference?

Comment: @user2766423 If you really want a reason: it probably executes faster.

Comment: @Havelock readability, also

Comment: I imagine a [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) would be better than 2 queries & 2 foreach. If you post {EDIT Question} table details we may be able to point you in the correct direction

Comment: Ok I tried a JOIN and posted it here now. However I now get the error "mysql error 1054: Unknown column 'required_items.name'", but that is in fact the column name